# Loop HTML table and add the identical items and its calculated amount to another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <table border="1" id="topTable">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="topTableBody">
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Oranges</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Strawberry</td>
          <td>60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cherry</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Guava</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Strawberry</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button id="btn">Click</button>
  </br>

  <div>
    <table border="1" id="bottomTable">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="bottomTableBody">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I press on the button I want it to loop through the top table and get the item names that're alike and add them in one row with the sold amount combined in the bottom table ex: apples will have their own row with a sold amount of 75 and others who have no names that're alike will have their own row such as Oranges with the sold amount also.

Comment: No apparent effort to solve the problem. What have you tried?

Comment: Here's a hint: something like `firstTable.getElementsByTagName("td");` will return a list that will have fruit names in even positions and quantities in odd.

Comment: Lovely! Another "question" that looks more like a job ad seeking for short-term contractors

Comment: Here are few simple hints... Try it before posting a question next time... Select the element and get collection of childNodes... loop and append elements to new table...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you can use JQuery.**
(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inanda/o9axgkaz/):

```
  jQuery('#btn').on('click', function() {
        var sumMap = {};
//Iterate through table rows
    $("table tbody tr").each(function () {
        if (sumMap[$(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').text()]) {            
            sumMap[$(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').text()] =  sumMap[$(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').text()] +Number($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text());
        } else {

            sumMap[$(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').text()] = Number($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text());
        }  

    })
//Append result to the other table
    $.each(sumMap, function (i, val) {
      $('#bottomTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>'+val+'</td>');
    });

    });
```

**Pure javascript:**
(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inanda/2dmwudfj/ ):

```
appendResultToBottomTable= function() {
    var sumMap = calculate();
    appendResultToTable('bottomTableBody', sumMap);
}

function calculate() {
    var table = document.getElementById("topTableBody");
    var map = {};
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    var itemType=(row.cells[0].innerText || row.cells[0].textContent);
    var value=(row.cells[1].innerText || row.cells[1].textContent);
        if (map[itemType]) {

        map[itemType] =  map[itemType] +Number(value);
    } else {

        map[itemType] = Number(value);
    }    
}
    return map;
}

function appendResultToTable(tableId, sumMap){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    for (var item in sumMap){
  var row   = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
  var cellItem  = row.insertCell(0);
        var cellValue  = row.insertCell(1);

  cellItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
        cellValue.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sumMap[item]));
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is applicable for your project to use external libraries, you can do it with code like below:

```
alasql('SELECT Item,SUM(CONVERT(INT,Sold)) AS Sold \
    INTO HTML("#res",{headers:true}) \
    FROM HTML("#topTable",{headers:true}) \
    GROUP BY Item');
```

Here:

1. `SELECT Item, SUM(Sold) FROM data GROUP BY Item` is a regular SQL expression to group and sum data from the table
2. `CONVERT(INT,Sold)` conversion procedure from string to INT type
3. `FROM HTML()` and `INTO HTML()` special functions to read/write data from/to HTML table, `{headers:true}` is a parameter to use headers
4. I added some minor CSS code (for table and cells borders), because Alasql generates the "plain" HTML table.

See the working snippet below.

(Disclaimer: I am an author of [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library)

```js
function run() {
    alasql('SELECT Item,SUM(CONVERT(INT,Sold)) AS Sold INTO HTML("#res",{headers:true}) FROM HTML("#topTable",{headers:true}) GROUP BY Item');
}
```

```css
#res table {
   border:1px solid black;
}
#res table td, th{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"> </script>

<div>
    <table border="1" id="topTable">
      <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Sold</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="topTableBody">
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Apples</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Oranges</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Strawberry</td>
          <td>60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cherry</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Guava</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Strawberry</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button id="btn" onclick="run()">Click</button>
  </br>

<div id="res"></div>
```